# Two different answers for particle-reservoir system in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am taking a first course in statistical mechanics. Consider a one-particle system $S$ connected to a heat bath $R$. The total energy of $R + S$ is $U$, which stays fixed, and the total number of particles is $N$ so that the reservoir has $N-1$ particles, and this stays fixed throughout, too. We want to find the most probable energy state of the one-particle system. The Boltzmann factor tells us that $P(s) \propto \exp(-\epsilon_s/\tau)$, so that the ground states $\epsilon_ s =0$ is most probable.

However, I also learned that when two systems are put into thermal contact (as $S, R$ are here), then at equilibrium the average energy per particle is (with overwhelming probability) equal between the two systems. This suggests that the most probable $\epsilon_s$ for the one-particle system is that which solves $\epsilon_s = \frac{U - \epsilon_s}{N-1} \implies \epsilon_s = \frac{U}{N}$. Of course, $\frac{U}{N} \neq 0$ so the two approaches disagree. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

In statistical mechanics, the macrovariable $U$ is defined as the average energy:

$$U=\langle H\rangle$$

> However, I also learned that when two systems are put into thermal
> contact (as S,R are here), then at equilibrium the **average** energy per
> particle is (with overwhelming probability) equal between the two
> systems.

It is not the energy (per particle) but the **average** energy (per particle) that is equal. The average is already summed over possibilities (or equivalently over time), it is not something that varies or can be given a probability.

In an equilibrium state of $R+S$, the particle $S$ will have its energy constantly changing, constantly moving between levels. Each of the levels will have a probability. The average is the average over all possibilities (or equivalently over time) and is a constant by definition.

You can imagine the distribution looks like this:

[image]

The most probable state is the ground state. The average is higher than the ground state. The more the temperature increases, the more the distribution gives weight to the higher levels, the more the average increases, but the first level always has the highest probability.

Note: I ignored the degeneracy of the level for simplicity. Normally, you should take it into account to find the state with highest probability. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics#Derivations

Answer (score 1):

To add to Benoit's answer, when we are dealing with one particle, its energy fluctuates drastically. Even though the ground state has the highest probability, other states have comparable (though lower) energy, and they can be observed. In fact, a single particle in contact with a bath is the same as *any* particle in the bath: it has an energy that fluctuates from very low to very large, as the particle collides with other particles. Clearly, since the energy of the system is fixed at some value it is not possible that all particles would have the ground energy.

Here is a qualitative explanation of the math behind this result. Suppose that the energy levels are $\epsilon_1=1$, $\epsilon_2=2$, etc. If we have 10 particles with total energy $E=20$ it is clear that not all can have the ground energy $\epsilon_1$. We calculate the distribution of energies by collecting all the ways to form $E=20$ as the sum of $N=10$ energies, then count the number of times each energy appears in the collection. What we find is that the smaller energies appear more frequently because they can fit in more ways to produce the desired sum.  When we do the math the distribution of energies is exponential and its maximum is at the lowest energy.  Still, the probability of $\epsilon_2$ is only slightly smaller than that, which makes it almost as probable as the ground state, and so on. Indeed, the exponential distribution is a very wide distribution that covers a pretty wide range of energies.